# Variable in Pango Markup

Tags: pango, pygobject

I am using Python 2.7 and PyGObject 3.0. (This is VERY important! the PyGObject syntax changed with 3.0!)

I need to put a variable in place of a string in a markup, so the output is formatted. This is the code I have for formatting a standard string in a label.

```
lbl_tile1.set_markup('<span font_family="serif" font = "48" weight = "bold">W</span>')
```

However, I need to use the data in a variable. The following changes the text, but removes the formatting.

```
lbl_tile1.set_markup('<span font_family="serif" font = "48" weight = "bold">W</span>')
lbl_tile1.set_text(t[0])
```

I need to get the variable "t[0]" in place of "W" in the formatted string. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need use the set_text method. You can put the data on set_markup method.

For example:

```
lbl_tile1.set_markup('<span font_family="serif" font = "48" weight = "bold">{0}</span>'.format(t[0]))
```

Comment: For some reason, this answer never came through on my feed...thank you! This really helps.